# Responsive vertical center elements inside div

Tags: html, css, position

I need to verticaly align elements inside div container. Elements looks like on image below. 
With this code, I was able to nicely overwrap big picture on the left, but text and small picture still doing what it wants. 
I need to avoid flexbox, since I need to support also IE8, or atleast IE9. 
I've been trought several solutions, also with tables or absolute positions, but propably I've always did something wrong...

Thank you for helping me get of this :)

[image: responsive vertical center elements]

HTML

```
    <section class="contact">
        <div class="adress">
            <h4>abc</h4>
            <span>acbd<br>
            efgh</span>
            <span>tyre<br>
            asdsad<br>
            cxzcasd</span>
            <img src="img/ccc-map.png" alt="map-ccc">
        </div>
        <div class="map">
            <img src="img/ccc-g-map.png" alt="google-map">
        </div>
    </section>
```

SCSS

```
.contact {
    border: 1.5px solid $grey; 
    width: 100%;

    .adress {
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
        padding: 2%;

        h4 {
            font-size: 130%;
        }

        span {
            font-size: 100%;
        }

        img {
            width: 45%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
    .map {
        float: right;
        width: 60%;
        padding: 1%;

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    } 
}
.contact::after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: In the image & the code you gave, the text inside `.adress` seems to be already vertically centered. Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing block-level elements like `h4` and inline like `img` and expecting them to align properly, possible but there's a simpler solution, add a third cell:

```css
.contact{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
.contact > div{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:8px;
}
.contact img{
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.pic{
  width: 100px;
}
.map{
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
  
  <!-- Create three cells instead! -->
  
  <div class="adress">
    <h4>abc</h4> 
    <span>
      acbd<br>
      efgh
    </span>
    <span>
      tyre<br>
      asdsad<br>
      cxzcasd
    </span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100/fac" alt="map-ccc">
  </div>
  
  <div class="map">
    <img src="//placehold.it/500x300/fac" alt="google-map">
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works perfect, but I still have small issue. I have border, wrapped around contact section, and on right side this border is missing. Look like it's covered bz something, but despite I've hide images, this border still missing. Can you please help me fix also that ?

Comment: This is super strange. It seems that this problem appears only Chrome. I've opened site in Firefox and everything works fine. Problem is like I've described above, but it behaves like that:
When I'm resizing browser window, every second resized pixel hide right border of this section. Superstrange. Interesting is, that it's not doing on any other sections on page, where the same border is applyied. Only here, in section with your code. Do you have any ideas why? :)

Comment: @JZK  I have no idea what you're doing, works absolutely fine in all browsers as you can see here: http://jsbin.com/vorogo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Since our code is the same, only difference was border as I'm using 1.5 and you 2px. It seems that chrome has problem with rendering it properly. I've deleted display: table; from contact and vuala, it works even with 1.5px border now. Question is, is it good solution ? So far looks usable

Comment: @JZK don't use half pixels precision. A pixel is a pixel.

Comment: it does also with 1px in my browser. 
With 1px (which I need) it works normally only, when I delete display: table; Now I'm running it without display: table; and it works fine. But I'm unsure if this is good approach

Comment: @JZK sorry I cannot reproduce your issue (although I've seen it before so I know what you're referring to). So I'm afraid you should use what works best for you (and in all browsers)