# making an img responsive on all devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive webpage but somehow I'm struggling with the image of the robot and the message, just let me show you what I'm talking about

as you see here is the view on a Galaxy S5 and that's pretty good 
[image]

but the problem is when I switch to pixel 2, for example, the message translated a little bit to the top as you see below:

[image]

It's the same problem if I shift to any other device. On some devices it's good looking and on some it's totally translated to the top. I tried media queries for different devices but I found myself doing a lot and I don't think it's the best practice. Please provide any optimal solution and thank you in advance.

Here is a code snipet of my code: https://codepen.io/Amoocris/pen/vPWOpX

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-box">
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Projects</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav__items"><a class="main-nav__link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="text">
  <h3 class="name">M.Amine Elwere</h3>
  <h1 class="big-heading">Front-end</h1>
  <h1 class="big-heading-2">Web developer</h1>
</div>
<div class="vector-1">
  <img src="../vector/Png for the web/header minou.png" data-aos="fade-up" class="img-header" alt="">
  <img src="../vector/Png for the web/png-dialogue-2.png"  data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="4000" class="img-dialogue" alt="">
  <h1 class="dialogue"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="5000">HEYY!...</h1>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
   * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   body {
     font-family: Roboto;
     color: #33cccc;
     background-color: #ffffcc;
   }

   .header-box {
     width: 100vw;
     height: 90vh;
     background-color: #33cccc;
     -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
     clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 76%, 0% 100%);
     position: relative;
   }

   .main-nav {
     display: flex;
     list-style-type: none;
     justify-content: space-around;
     width: 100vw;
     text-align: right;
   }

   .main-nav__items {
     text-decoration: none;
   }

   .main-nav__link {
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #ffffcc;
   }

   .name {
     font-family: Roboto;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
     top: -7%;
     left: 3%;
     font-size: 1rem;
   }

   .text {
     font-family: Roboto;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 2rem;
     color: #ffffcc;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 40%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   }

   .img-header {
     width: 30%;
     height: auto;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0px;
   }

   .img-dialogue {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 7rem;
     left: 2rem;
   }

/* .vector-1{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
} */

   .dialogue {
     position: absolute;
     font-family: inherit;
     color: inherit;
     bottom: 24%;
     left: 17%;
   }

.big-heading-2{
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  animation-name: moveInLeft;
  animation-duration: 1.5s
}

.big-heading{
  font-size: 3rem;
  animation-name: moveInRight;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}


 }
```

Comment: Have you considered using Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)?

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486156/responsive-vertical-center-elements-inside-div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the `.vector-1` div position relative. That way, the `.dialogue` class wil be positiond using the parent div and not the web page. If you try that, you should change the position of the `.dialogue` class.

And by the way. You should not use more than 1 h1 on your web page. The h1 element is the title of the page, so you should only use it once :)

if you have any other questions, please let me know